# Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax not registering ajax type on my machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax

I have this strange issue where Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax works as expected  for all other team members but not for me. I get

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'AjaxClass' is undefined
```

I also created a sample application with minimal code for testing that looks like this -

```
public class AjaxClass
{
    [Ajax.AjaxMethod(Ajax.HttpSessionStateRequirement.Read)]
    public string SaveDataUsageAgreement(int agcount)
    {
        return "111";
    }

}
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(AjaxClass));
    }
}
```

Then in js file i have

```
var result = AjaxClass.SaveDataUsageAgreement("222");
```

And i have this in my web.config under `system.web`

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="POST,GET" path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

But this piece of code gives me above mentioned error.
I use `Visual Studio 2013` and `.Net framework 4.0`

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you see in the console & network tab?

Comment: Nothing is displayed in the network tab as the <AjaxClass> is not defined on the client and hence no network calls are made. In the console i see the same undefined error.

Answer (score 1):

Please put below code in `"<system.webServer>"` rather than `system.web`

```
<system.webServer> 
    <handlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET" path="ajax/*.ashx" name="Ajax"  type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

It is working fine.

Comment: Please put above code in  <system.webServer>  rather than system.web